# iOS - UIButton retains background image

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I am presenting some buttons with big images. When the button is clicked, it is removed from the superview successfully. The button is also being de initialised. Still the image is kept in memory, and if several buttons are presented afterwards, the app crashes due to memory constraints. The button gets removed from the superview, but the image is not released.

Test Code:

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        let button = UIButton(frame: view.bounds)
        button.setBackgroundImage(getImage(), for: .normal)
        view.addSubview(button)
        button.addAction(UIAction { [weak button] _ in
            button?.removeFromSuperview()
        }, for: .touchUpInside)
    }


    func getImage() -> UIImage? {
        if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "super", ofType: "png") {
            return UIImage(contentsOfFile: path)
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

I don't see any retain cycles there, for the image to be kept in memory.

And IMPORTANT: If I call `button?.removeFromSuperview()` from any other button or method, the image gets successfully released:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        let buttonWithImage = UIButton(frame: view.bounds)
        buttonWithImage.setBackgroundImage(getImage(), for: .normal)
        view.addSubview(buttonWithImage)


        let dismissingButton = UIButton(frame: view.bounds)
        view.addSubview(dismissingButton)

        dismissingButton.addAction(UIAction { [weak buttonWithImage] _ in
            buttonWithImage?.removeFromSuperview()
        }, for: .touchUpInside)
    }


    func getImage() -> UIImage? {
        if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "super", ofType: "png") {
            return UIImage(contentsOfFile: path)
        }
        return nil
    }

}
```

I am out of ideas for this issue. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check if this works for you:

```
button.addAction(UIAction(handler: { action in
    let button = action.sender as! UIButton
    button.removeFromSuperview()
}), for: .touchUpInside)
```